# Django "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren’t loaded yet.” and production server restart

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I tried to restart my production server and got this error: “django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren’t loaded yet.”

I reset git to a steady version, and the error is still occurring. Does anyone have any idea what could have suddenly caused this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 216, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder:
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Is there any more of the traceback you haven't shown? I would usually expect to see some references to your project in the traceback, but it all seems to be from Django.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't have an environment variable set in ~/.bash_profile, that was breaking everything